# How to find the second occurrence of a string using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have atleast two occurrence of the same button, I want to click a specific one which will most likely be the second button. I have these two buttons in the same tbody

...

```
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$21')">...</a></td>
```

I use this python command to click on the button but I can only get the first occurrence

```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("...").click()
```

how can I click on Page$21?

Comment: Can you elaborate more.I can see only one anchor tag.As you have mentioned you have two same buttons where is the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using an attribute = value css selector with contains operator

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href*='Page$21']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough information for me to give a full answer, but in general, you an find multiple (or all) the occurrences of some feature in HTML with the BeautifulSoup `find_all` method.  E.g.

```py
In [61]: html = '<div>hi <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a> and
    ...: goodbye <a href="https://google.com">Google</a></div>'

In [62]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

In [63]: soup.find_all('a')
Out[63]:
[<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>,
 <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>]
```

Check out the BeautifulSoup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) for more.  Notably, you don't just need to search for tags by name, but you can supply an arbitrary function so long as it returns True or False given a tag. E.g.

```py
In [64]: soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a')
Out[64]:
[<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>,
 <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>]
```

Given a tag, you may find the `.has_attr` and `.get` methods useful:

```py
In [71]: soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.has_attr('href') and 'st
    ...: ack' in tag.get('href'))
Out[71]: [<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>]
```

Note that if you supply `.get` with an attribute which is absent, it will return `None`.